# Create Image at run time - aForge?

Tags: c#, image

I need to create a blank image at run time. I've tried creating one on the fly and creating one, saving it to disk then accessing it. I'm serializing an array of them, so I cant skip one. I've also looked at aForge, some neat texture methods, but I'm not familiar with their documentation. I tried to quick implement some things I found here..

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(255, 255);
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)))
    {
        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    }
```

and

```
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(255, 255))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
        }
        bitmap.Save(dirPath + "\\" + "_Error_Image.png");
    }
```

neither worked out. Does anyone have a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "neither worked out"? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: you want a "empty" image,or a image filled with black - Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0) - is black,are you missing the alpha or effectively,what do you need?

Comment: You have't draw anything in bitmap object base from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that its this you want?

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(255, 255))

bitmap.Save(dirPath + "\\" + "_Error_Image.png");
```

If by blank you mean with nothing this will do it and to set your color to transparent if you want for future reference `Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)` - first parameter is the Alpha where 0 = transparent and 255=fully opaque.